# What is wrong with my Java port of this C++ CRC32 function?

Tags: java, c++, crc

I have the follow CRC function:

```
unsigned long Checksummer::crc32 (unsigned long crc, char *buf, unsigned long len)
{
   unsigned long crc_table[256];
   int i, k;
   for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      unsigned long c = (unsigned long) i;
      for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) 
         c = c & 1 ? 0xedb88320 ^ (c >> 1) : c >> 1;
      crc_table[i] = c;
   }

   crc = crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
   while (len--) 
      crc = crc_table[((int)crc ^ (*buf++)) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
   return crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
}
```

I am trying to port this code to Java so that I can calculate CRCs on multiple platforms. My ported code below produces a different result. What am I doing wrong?

```
static long getCrc32 (long crc, char[] buf, long len)
{
   long crc_table[] = new long[256];
   int i, k;
   for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      long c = ( long)i;
      for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) 
         c = (c & 1) == 1 ? 0xedb88320 ^ (c >> 1) : c >> 1;
      crc_table[i] = c;
    }

    /* Calculate crc on buf */
    crc = crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
    int j = 0;
    while (len-- != 0){ 
       crc = crc_table[((int)crc ^ (buf[(int)j++])) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);}
    return crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
}
```

Comment: I can give you an advice to test >> operator in java. probably, it is acting the different way, than in cpp(i.e. there is no unsigned integers in java

Comment: `long` is signed in Java. So, `>>` returns different result for some values in C and in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is two bytes in Java; use `byte` instead (`char` in C and C++ are one byte by definition).

`long` is eight bytes in Java; use `int` instead (assuming `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` on your C++ platform, which is the norm).

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is this line:

```
c = (c & 1) == 1 ? 0xedb88320 ^ (c >> 1) : c >> 1;
```

In C++, `c&1` is true iff it's not zero; it doesn't have to be 1.

Additionally, you should probably use `>>>` instead of `>>`.  The former always shifts a 0 into the leftmost bit, just like the C operator `>>` does for unsign.

Comment: "*In C++, c&1 is true iff it's not zero; it doesn't have to be 1.*" What else _could_ it be other than `0` or `1`? (Not downvoting, but this makes zero sense.)

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for not thinking before responding.  Sorry :(